# How do I replace a sifr font of an existing site without changing the font size in the css?

Tags: sifr

I've been tasked with re-skining a site that uses sifr extensively.  Unfortunately the new glyphs seem to render both taller and fatter than the old ones, necessitating changes to the font-size of every instance.   The site is quite large with many different templates and one-off page layouts, so identifying and tuning each instance will be time consuming.

Besides cutting down on the obviously excessive use of sIFR, or getting a better font is there any other workaround?  The only thing I can think of is calculating a new font-size in javascript before I make this replacement.

Answer (score 0):

With sIFR 3, you could:

- Use the `.sIFR-active` class to specify a different font size for the elements that will be replaced when sIFR is active
- Hard-code a pixel font size in the `css` parameter to `sIFR.replace()`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I suppose I could add a rule for each replacement, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

Using FontForge I was able to tweak the Em size of the typeface and generate a new font.  The change doesn't appear to have effected the display of any of the glyphs I'm concerned with.  Can you think of any reason not to use this modified version of the font?

Comment: Uhm, I don't think I know enough about FontForge and Flash to answer that. Give it a shot!